# Cómo puedo convertir en NA sólo algunos valores de un data frame en R

Tags: r, rstudio, eliminar

Sé eliminar valores de UNA columna convirtiéndolos en NA, sin embargo, no logro encontrar información de cómo hacer esto en todo un data frame.
Agradezco la ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Pues simplemente extiende la solución que ya tienes para una columna en todas, mediante un ciclo `for` o eventualmente con `apply()`, si el tema es más complejo o no entiendes lo que  te comento, te sugiero que muestres un ejemplo de lo que estás haciendo y a dónde quieres llegar.